# Boost Interprocess share memory deletion, permissions and output files

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am using Boost Interprocess library to share memory between two processes.

I am using the following to allocate shared memory block, an attached vector, named mutex and a named condition variable:

```
using ShmemAllocator = allocator<T, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
using MyVector = vector<T, ShmemAllocator>;

segment.reset(new managed_shared_memory(create_only, blockName, numBytes));

const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment->get_segment_manager());
vec = segment->construct<MyVector>(sharedVectorName)(alloc_inst);

named_mutex.reset(new named_mutex(create_only, mutexName));
cond_empty.reset(new named_condition(create_only, conditionVName));
```

and the following to delete:

```
named_mutex::remove(mutexName);
named_condition::remove(conditionVName);
shared_memory_object::remove(blockName);
```

To check the memory was being deleted correctly I ran a stress test:

```
while(counter < 1000000)
{
    MySharedMemoryObj s;
    ++counter;
}
```

(Relying on RAII for the destructor to delete the shared memory)

I have three questions:

1. Do I need to delete the vector, because it's part of the segment anyway?
2. The above works, but on one particular occasion it didn't and threw a Boost Interprocess exception, saying it did not have permission to access the memory. What causes this/is there a way to avoid it?
3. I have noticed that the above code seems to generate binary files in /tmp named `outputXXXXXXXXXXX`. What are these? They aren't being deleted and therefore accumulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Do I need to delete the vector, because it's part of the segment anyway?

Technically, not really here (assuming you use the shared-memory allocator too). However, it's a bad practice to skip destruction especially if your destructor has logic (is not *trivial*).

> 2. The above works, but on one particular occasion it didn't and threw a Boost Interprocess exception, saying it did not have permission to access the memory. What causes this/is there a way to avoid it?

Make sure that the program runs as with the intended user when creating the shared segment. This is what lends it the file-level access permissions.

E.g. if you create the segment as `root`, you should not be able to open it as another user.

> 3. I have noticed that the above code seems to generate binary files in /tmp named outputXXXXXXXXXXX. What are these? They aren't being deleted and therefore accumulate.

That doesn't make a lot of sense. The paths suggest you're on a POSIX system. On POSIX shmem usually exists in `/dev/shm` and I don't see a need for temporary files.

I'd suggest that the temporary files might be an artifact of other programs (like your IDE?)

### Suggested Simplifications:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_condition.hpp>
#include <vector>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

static auto blockName        = "4f72909d-8265-4260-9bb1-6bd58f63812c";
static auto sharedVectorName = "54714711";
static auto mutexName        = "b4eb63e0";
static auto conditionVName   = "f7a95857";

template <typename T> using ShmemAllocator = bip::allocator<T, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
template <typename T> using MyVector = std::vector<T, ShmemAllocator<T> >;

int main() {
    bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::create_only, "blockName", 10<<20u);

    auto vec = segment.construct<MyVector<int> >(sharedVectorName)(segment.get_segment_manager());

    bip::named_mutex named_mutex(bip::create_only, mutexName);
    bip::named_condition named_condition(bip::create_only, conditionVName);
}
```

Or, depending on what you want to synchronize, make the synchronization primitives members of the shared data:

```
struct SharedData {
    using allocator_type = ShmemAllocator<int>;

    template <typename A>
    SharedData(A alloc) : _vec(alloc) {}

    MyVector<int> _vec;
    bip::interprocess_mutex _mx;
    bip::interprocess_condition _cond;
};

int main(int argc, char**) {
    bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_or_create, "2fc51845-3d9b-442b-88ee-f6fd1725e8b0", 10<<20u);

    auto& data = *segment.find_or_construct<SharedData>("sharedData")(segment.get_segment_manager());
}
```

### Simple Multi-Producer/Multi Consumer Queue:

Models a queue with maximum capacity of 10 elements.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_condition.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex> // unique_lock
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

template <typename T> using ShmemAllocator = bip::allocator<T, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
template <typename T> using MyVector = std::vector<T, ShmemAllocator<T> >;

struct SharedData {
    using allocator_type = ShmemAllocator<int>;

    template <typename A>
    SharedData(A alloc) : _vec(alloc) {}

    MyVector<int> _vec;
    bip::interprocess_mutex _mx;
    bip::interprocess_condition _cond;

    using lock_type = std::unique_lock<bip::interprocess_mutex>;
    lock_type wait_for_empty() {
        lock_type lk(_mx);
        _cond.wait(lk, [=] { return _vec.empty(); });
        return lk;
    }

    void push(int v) {
        lock_type lk(_mx);
        _cond.wait(lk, [=] { return _vec.size() < 10; }); // wait for free space
        _vec.push_back(v);
        _cond.notify_all();
    }

    bool pop(boost::posix_time::time_duration timeout, int& out) {
        lock_type lk(_mx);

        // wait for message
        auto deadline = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() + timeout;
        if (_cond.timed_wait(lk, deadline, [=] { return !_vec.empty(); })) {
            out = _vec.back();
            _vec.pop_back();
            _cond.notify_all();
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char**) {
    bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_or_create, "2fc51845-3d9b-442b-88ee-f6fd1725e8b0", 10<<20u);

    auto& data = *segment.find_or_construct<SharedData>("sharedData")(segment.get_segment_manager());

    if (argc>1) {
        // "server"
        std::cout << "Waiting for queue to be depleted\n";
        data.wait_for_empty();

        for (int i = 0; i<20; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Pushing " << i << "\n";
            data.push(i);
        }
    } else {
        // "client"
        int what;
        while (data.pop(boost::posix_time::seconds(1), what))
            std::cout << "Popped " << what << "\n";

        std::cout << "Timeout reached, bye\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Gave some more suggestions using anomymous mutex/conditions and a queue demo

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I really appreciate it. My two processes will be run from different user accounts. Is there a way I can create the shared memory so that the reading process can be started under any user?

Comment: Yes. Modify the file permissions so both users have access (e.g. by adding them to the same group). On windows, there's SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is Linux. The user of first process has highest user rights. The second process is run under a user created for a software vendor and their software has to run under that account. Would your suggestion give the vendor user the same permissions as our user? Obviously we don't want them having permissions across entire system.

Comment: Re-read: _"Modify the file permissions so both users have access (e.g. by adding them to the same group)"_ This is basic UNIX file permissions. The usual thing to do is to create a group, make the shared file owned by that group (`chgrp`/`chown`), grant the group appropriate permissions (`chmod g+rw`), and add all users that require access to that group (`adduser <user> <group>`). This is the same as most services like `wwwroot`, `adm`, `plugdev`, `docker` etc. On my home desktop there are a few users in the `kids` group :) It takes some planning, but UNIX permissions are conceptually simple

Comment: I'd expect [SF] to have lots of information, or otherwise Google and your sysadmin will help

Comment: If (for some reason) I cannot use Linux permissions, programatically I could use this constructor: basic_managed_shared_memory(create_only_t, const char *name, size_type size, const void *addr = 0, const permissions& perm = permissions()) However, to use the permissions argument I need to provide an addr argument?

Comment: @user997112 That's exactly the constructor I referred to earlier. So that sounds pretty confused because you're basically asking "If for some reason I can't use XXX I could use XXX" - it's the same thing. Also, the `addr` argument defaults to `0` so it seems pretty obvious what you should pass for it if you don't want to change the defaults.

Comment: I'm still getting the exception thrown even though I am calling:

permissions perm;   perm.set_unrestricted();
        segment.reset(new managed_shared_memory(open_or_create, shared_memory_name, numBytes, 0, perm));

Comment: @user997112 the permissions are only exacted when creating. Did you remove the shared memory object before recreating with "unrestricted" permissions? Also, check that [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) doesn't make the _effective_ permissions less broad.

Comment: I will create another question with the same SO tags, so I can copy the relevant code pertaining to this later issue. Thanks for your continued assistance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348027/boost-interprocess-failing-to-open-or-create-shared-memory