# Boost Interprocess named_mutex semaphore file permissions

Tags: memory-management, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am creating my shared memory using the below, trying either to open or create and setting unrestricted permissions.

```
void createMemory(const int numBytes)
{
    permissions perm;
    perm.set_unrestricted();

    segment.reset(new managed_shared_memory(open_or_create, memory_name, numBytes, 0, perm));

    // Exception throw on this line
    mutex.reset(new named_mutex(open_or_create, mutex_name, perm));

    cond_empty.reset(new named_condition(open_or_create, cv_name, perm));

    const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment->get_segment_manager());
    vec = segment->find_or_construct<MyVector>(vector_name)(alloc_inst);
}
```

This creates two files for named_mutex, the shared memory and the (semaphore?) file:

```
mutex_name
sem.mutex_name
```

The first file has permissions which are fine, but the second file is created with restrictive permissions, preventing the second user from opening it.

I have configured user in the bashrc profile of the first user, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. How else can I force this sem file to have relaxed permissions?

Answer (score 0):

This answers it:

[POSIX shared memory and semaphores permissions set incorrectly by open calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909505/posix-shared-memory-and-semaphores-permissions-set-incorrectly-by-open-calls)

You set umask programatically to zero and then restore the previous umask value.