# Boost Interprocess named_mutex causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I'm using boost interprocess to share memory but very rarely getting a segmentation fault when I try to take a boost::interprocess:named_mutex using boost::interprocess::scoped_lock.

I am only running the writer process. This process owns the shared memory and does not destroy it (unless the application is closing down). The application creates the shared memory using SharedDataCommon class (see bottom of question) which encpsulates all the boost inner workings and then later on I call write(), which tries to retrieves the named_mutex but it seg faults.

The segmentation fault occurs within

> boost/interprocess/sync/posix/named_semaphore.hpp

line 63:

```
void wait()
   {  semaphore_wait(mp_sem); }     // seg faults here
```

It's as if someone changes the permissions to the semaphore whilst the application is running, except they didn't. Is there a log to check whether permissions were changed prior to the segmentation fault?

The segmentation fault is occurring when taking the scoped lock prior to a write:

```
bool write(const std::vector<T>& vec, const bool clearFirst = false)
{
    bip::scoped_lock<bip::named_mutex> lock(*sdc.mutex);   // seg faults here

    try
    {
        sdc.vec->reserve(sdc.vec->size() + vec.size());
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Not enough room to write elements" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if(clearFirst)
    {
        sdc.vec->clear();
    }

    for(const auto& item : vec)
    {
        sdc.vec->push_back(item);
    }

    sdc.cond_empty->notify_all();

    return true;
}
```

sdc is an instance of SharedDataCommon (see below) encapsulating the boost::interprocess components.

I set temporarily set umask so the shared memory is readable by multiple Linux users.

```
template<typename T>
struct SharedDataCommon
{
    using ShmemAllocator = bip::allocator<T, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
    using MyVector = bip::vector<T, ShmemAllocator>;

    void initialise(const std::string& tag, const int numBytes, const bool ownMemory)
    {
        const std::string sharedMemoryName = tag + "_shared_memory";
        const std::string sharedVectorName = tag + "_shared_vector";
        const std::string sharedMutexName = tag + "_shared_mutex";
        const std::string sharedCVName = tag + "_shared_cv";

        tag_name = tag;
        shared_memory_name = sharedMemoryName;
        shared_mutex_name = sharedMutexName;
        shared_vector_name = sharedVectorName;
        shared_cv_name = sharedCVName;
        destroy_memory = ownMemory;

        if(ownMemory)
        {
            destroyMemory(tag);
        }

        createMemory(numBytes);
    }

    void createMemory(const int numBytes)
    {
        const mode_t old_umask = umask(0);

        bip::permissions perm;
        perm.set_unrestricted();
        segment.reset(new bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::open_or_create, shared_memory_name.c_str(), numBytes, 0, perm));

        mutex.reset(new bip::named_mutex(bip::open_or_create, shared_mutex_name.c_str(), perm));

        const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment->get_segment_manager());
        vec = segment->find_or_construct<MyVector>(shared_vector_name.c_str())(alloc_inst);

        cond_empty.reset(new bip::named_condition(bip::open_or_create, shared_cv_name.c_str(), perm));

        umask(old_umask);
    }

    static void destroyMemory(const std::string& tag)
    {
        const std::string sharedMemoryName = tag + "_shared_memory";
        const std::string sharedMutexName = tag + "_shared_mutex";
        const std::string sharedCVName = tag + "_shared_cv";

        bip::named_mutex::remove(sharedMutexName.c_str());
        bip::named_condition::remove(sharedCVName.c_str());     
        bip::shared_memory_object::remove(sharedMemoryName.c_str());
    }

    ~SharedDataCommon()
    {
        if(destroy_memory)
        {
            destroyMemory(tag_name);
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<bip::named_mutex>           mutex{nullptr};
    MyVector*                                   vec{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<bip::managed_shared_memory> segment{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<bip::named_condition>       cond_empty;
    bool                                        destroy_memory{false};
    std::string                                 shared_vector_name;
    std::string                                 shared_mutex_name;
    std::string                                 shared_cv_name;
    std::string                                 shared_memory_name;
    std::string                                 tag_name;
};
```

I don't see anything which explains why the problem would occur some of the time?

Comment: "Is there a log to check whether permissions were changed prior to the segmentation fault?" - what gives you the idea it should be a permissions problem? Does it make sense for `lock()` to segfault in such cases?

Comment: I'd run this under valgrind or with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`

Comment: @sehe hi (again). I'm limited how I can run it because the application is a module within a third party framework. I figured the only things which would cause seg faults are permissions or the named_mutex being deleted earlier. Is there anything else that could explain a seg fault?

Comment: ASAN and UBSAN can be preloaded (`LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD`). Usually seg faults are caused by corruption or undefined behaviour.

Comment: @sehe Given my previous message (and the fact I am compiling with clang), is there any way to still use a memory sanitizer?

Comment: ^ see my comment. Also in the [FAQ: "Q: I've built my shared library with ASan. Can I run it with unsanitized executable?"](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using all these separate named entities, when you could simply use unnamed interprocess synchronization primitives inside the shared memory segment? See e.g. [Boost Interprocess share memory deletion, permissions and output files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289336/boost-interprocess-share-memory-deletion-permissions-and-output-files/50289625#50289625) (second example).

That at once removes a race condition between retrieving all the shared objects and actually synchronizing on the primitives.

---

The only thing I can reasonably see being outside the shared object is the `named_mutex` so you could *synchronize* the actual creation of the shared memory segment. However, looking at your code it looks like you fail to do precisely that:

```
    segment.reset(new bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::open_or_create, shared_memory_name.c_str(), numBytes, 0, perm));

    mutex.reset(new bip::named_mutex(bip::open_or_create, shared_mutex_name.c_str(), perm));
```

The mutex is created *after* the segment. Now, this may not be a problem when you control the order in which server and clients start. However, in such a case there clearly is no need for the separate named-mutex to exist.

---

It's also worrying that you destroy the memory without any synchronization:

```
destroyMemory(tag);
```

Comment: How can one synchronise destroying the named_mutex, you would need to do this within..... a mutex, surely?

Comment: I wasn't talking about that. Interesting as that might be it's a different question (and currently unrelated), and possibly one thats been asked before?

Comment: It is memory corruption. I put a char[1000] before and after the mutex and I can see something else in my application is writing either side of the mutex. Other than doing some dodgy raw memory access, or array overload, the runtime system must be aware that I have allocated the shared memory like I have? Just worried it's my implementation of the shared memory (there's no reader process, just the writer)